# TailwindCss in Development and PostCSS in Production

Tags: tailwind-css, create-react-app, postcss

im currently working an a very usual app based on Create-React-App. For the frontend im using TailwindCss and PostCss. This helps to build my prod-app.

Im at the beginning of my project and i have to do a lot of basic HTML work. Currently that means to me, that i can't use the benefits of the hot-reload functionality. Tailwind just deploys the used css classes. Not all. If i want to use another tailwind css class i havn't used since the last server start, i have to restart the development server.

What is the best way to get the benefits of a filtered css output for production, but to have all available classes in the development phase deployed?

I just tried to find a PostCss-Plugin that gives me whole content of the Tailwind-Css Files.
Eventually i added the Tailwind CDN to my project, but that seems not to be apppropriate to me.

Answer (score 0):

Im using a new npm package "npm-watch" du solve my problem. This package listen to changed files in my src folder and call the PostCss process from tailwind. This works for now.

I expected a easier way to do this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).